# Panel.Heading color change

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have this part of code:

```
<Panel>
  <Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Title toggle>
      Hello
    </Panel.Title>
  </Panel.Heading>
  <Panel.Collapse>
    <Panel.Body>
      Really wide body. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </Panel.Body>
  </Panel.Collapse>
</Panel>
```

I wish to change Panel.Heading color, but there are no docs regarding this element. Anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the color of the heading for a panel, you can set the `bsStyle` prop of `Panel`, like the following:

```
<Panel bsStyle="primary">
  <Panel.heading>
  ...
```

This will set the color of the top of the panel, based on Bootstrap's color styles.

Values you can use for `bsStyle` are:

- `default`
- `primary`
- `success`
- `info`
- `warning`
- `danger`

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3kxkxpv2p) that demonstrates this.

It's difficult to find documentation for this because `react-bootstrap` (and `reactstrap`) now use Bootstrap v4. **`Panel` was a part of Bootstrap v3, but has now been replaced with `Card`**. By digging around in some of the older versions of `react-bootstrap` (specifically their `bs3-dev` [branch](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/tree/bs3-dev)), you can look at [how they used `Panel`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/bs3-dev/test/PanelSpec.js) back then.

You'll notice that, in the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3kxkxpv2p), we need to add some older versions of the dependencies (`bootstrap` at `3.4.1` and `react-bootstrap` at `0.32.1`).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with react-bootstrap but just style with css? or
style={{backgroundColor:"anyColor"}}